# How can i display the input range-value while choosing the range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i display the value of the input range, while someone is choosing a range?

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>Temp: </td>
       <td>
           <span>[RANGE VALUE HERE]<span>
           <input type="range" value="75">
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this ***[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LLNWs/3/)***

EDITED for color:

```
$('span').text($('[type=range]').val());
$('[type=range]').change(function () {
    var myspan = $('span');
    myspan.text(this.value);
    if (this.value < 50) {
        myspan.css('color', 'blue');
    } else {
        myspan.css('color', 'black');
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you! Works nice. How can i change the color of the value, let's say IF value < 50, color should be blue?

Comment: @htmlNewbie - absolutely.. glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3enxx/1/):

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>Temp: </td>
       <td>
           <div id="vv">[RANGE VALUE HERE]</div>
            <input id="rn" type="range" value="75" />
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

js:

```
$("#rn").change(function(){
    $("#vv").text(this.value);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('input[type="range"]').change(function () {
        $(this).prev('span').text(this.value)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dkMAU/)